# Handling outputs from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am passing a 3-layer LSTM to the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` function. I'd like to handle the output from the `dynamic_rnn` function in a specific way: that is, I'd like to let `dynamic_rnn` output flow to a fully-connected layer. The output from `dynamic_rnn` is rank-3 tensor, with shape of `[batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_dim]`.

I used to pass `output[:, -1]`, whose shape is `[batch_size, hidden_dim]`, to the FC layer since I used to want to use only the last output of the `dynamic_rnn`.

However, this time I want to use the output of the whole sequence, that is `output[:]`, which is a 3-d tensor, but the weights of the connections to the FC layer are represented in 2-d tensor `W`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the code for [`tf.layers.dense`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L155) for an example of how any rank tensor (with an innermost depth dimension) can be handled in a layer.  Namely: `tf.matmul` knows how to apply a matrix multiply to a `3-tensor` with proper broadcasting:

`tf.matmul(A,W)` where `A` is shaped `[b,t,d]` and `W` is shaped `[d,e]` takes the inner product along the inner dimensions: the output's shape is `[b,t,e]`.  Adding the bias vector, shaped `[e]`, will similarly broadcast correctly.